# How to find parametric equation describing intersection between 6D surface and 2D plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to write some plotting software and I'm struggling to solve this problem.

Given the scalar-valued function $f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+(x_3-x_1)^2+6(x_4^2+x_5^2+x_6^2)}$, $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^6$ and some scalar $y$ I can form the level-set of the function with $f(\boldsymbol{x})-y=0$. I want to plot the intersection of the level set with a 2D plane, but I have no idea where to start.

A general solution would be ideal, but a good starting point would be to restrict the planes of interest to be the planes containing any two of the basis vectors and the origin (not sure if there's terminology for these planes).

Comment: If that plane is in generic position, then on it $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ (or some other quad of your choice) are linear functions of $x_5$ and $x_6$, proving that the intersection is a (possibly empty) conic. You can describe any 2D-subspace as a set of solutions of some linear homogeneous system of four equations in six unknowns. Find one such, and bring its matrix into reduced row echelon form. Mind you, that may not be the most "visually pleasing" way of parametrizing the 2D subspaces (or cosets of one). Don't ask me to defined "visually pleasing" rigorously :-)

Comment: (cont'd) Basically I mean that if we parametrize those planes by whatever coefficients remain in the last two columns of that $4\times 6$ matrix, then a subset of them may tend to infinity without the plane itself doing anything dramatic. Some kind of a normalization is probably recommended, but I don't have anything precise in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

You can split the $\mathbb R ^6$ domain of $\bf x$ into two $\mathbb R ^3$ independent domains
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 f({\bf x})^2  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\left( {x_1  - x_2 } \right)^2  + \left( {x_2  - x_3 } \right)^2
  + \left( {x_3  - x_1 } \right)^2 } \right) + 3\left( {x_4 ^2  + x_5 ^2  + x_6 ^2 } \right) =  \\ 
  = g({\bf y})^2  + h({\bf z})^2 \quad \left| {\,{\bf y},z \in \mathbb R ^3 } \right. \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
where
$g({\bf y})^2  = a^2 $ is a cylinder,
$h({\bf z})^2  = b^2 $ is a sphere.